# Mongoose Promise with bluebird and typescript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am developing an application with nodejs/typescript and a mongodb database.
To query the database, I am using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html).

I've just read an article from the mongoose documentation on [how to plug in an external promise library](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) and it is very simple:

```
import mongoose = require("mongoose");
import Promise = require("bluebird");
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

Doing this is working fine. But I'd like to extend/override the type of the promise that is returned.

Here is an example of a function:

```
public getModel= () => {
    return MyModel.findOne().exec();
}
```

This function returns a `_mongoose.Promise<MyModel>` and I'd like to return a bluebird `Promise<MyModel>` because I know that is a bluebird promise.

Is there is anyway to change/extend/override the return type of mongoose query ?
Should I write a custom definition file for my app ? Any others suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoose team updated the definition file and you can now plug in and use your own promise library by assigning the `MongoosePromise<T>`.

Create a main `.d.ts` file for your application and add this:

```
declare module "mongoose" {
    import Bluebird = require("bluebird");
    type MongoosePromise<T> = Bluebird<T>;
}
```

Reference this file in your project and now Mongoose returns Bluebird Promise !

This also works for others promises library.

**EDIT** latest typings version

```
declare module "mongoose" {
    import Bluebird = require("bluebird");
    type Promise<T> = Bluebird<T>;
}
```

See documentation [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/mongoose#promises)

Comment: where did you get the typings for mongoose? The [.d.ts file](https://github.com/louy/typed-mongoose) installed via `typings install mongoose` does not have reference to MongoosePromise

Comment: Post updated: Yes I got the typings from `typings install mongoose`. I was using typescript 1.9 but I know now typings comes with npm. also depends on the mongoose version. here is the latest version: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/mongoose/README.md

Comment: Ugh, I went straight to the code to find this: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/index.d.ts#L2573 Next time I'll have to read the doc :\

Answer (score 5):

`Promise` export as a variable in mongoose, so you can convert `mongoose` namespace as any first, and then set `Promise` to others.

1. if you are using `q` lib.

   - install `npm install --save q @types/q` first. `tsc` version >= 2.0.
   - then add `(<any>mongoose).Promise = Q.Promise;`
2. using `bluebird` lib, add code below.

   - `import Bluebird = require("bluebird");`
   - `(<any>mongoose).Promise = Bluebird;`

Comment: Ok interesting answer I'll give it a try ;-)

Comment: This worked beautifully for me, thanks!  After plugging in Q library as you suggested, I'm now able to use promises .then() .catch() and .done() as expected.  I believe it is worth noting that, as per Mongoose docs, "If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function."

Comment: This is the official reference: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/mongoose#promises

Answer (score 1):

> Should I write a custom definition file for my app

Yes. It will mostly be a find and replace of Promise in the mongoose definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not find any good documentation on how to write custom definition file and integrate it in a nodejs app. Is there any documentation in your book that I can use as a starting point ?

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, [there is an open issue](https://github.com/louy/typed-mongoose/issues/4) in the typings file that is installed if you use `typings install mongoose` to install the typings. Specificaly  [typings file that is loaded](https://github.com/louy/typed-mongoose/blob/master/index.d.ts#L1) imports [mpromise](https://github.com/types/npm-mpromise/), and that import statement results in inclusion of the full [mpromise module definition](https://github.com/types/npm-mpromise) file by typings and included in your `typings\modules\mongoose\index.d.ts` file.

Until this issue get's resolved, my workaround is to delete the module definition for `~mongoose~mpromise` and replace the following line in the `index.d.ts` file:

```
import * as Promise from '~mongoose~mpromise';
```

with this one:

```
import Promise = require( "bluebird");
```

This is admittedly a temporary stop-gap as another call to `typings install mongoose` would revert this fix. For the curious, my current set up includes: typings ( version 2.0.0 ), npm ( 3.10.9 ), and node ( v6.9.2 )