# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I'm using Mongoose and Bluebird with typescript. Mongoose is setup to return Bluebird promises, but I don't know how to "tell" TypeScript about it.

For instance, I have a `Message` Mongoose model, if I try to do the following:

```
new Message(messageContent)
  .save()
  .then(() => {...})
  .catch(next);
```

TypeScript complains that `Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'.` because it thinks that `.save()` (or any other Mongoose methods returning a Promise) returns a 'regular' Promise (which indeed doesn't have the `.catch()` method) instead of a Bluebird promise.

How can I change the return type of Mongoose methods so that TypeScript knows it is returning a Bluebird promise?

Comment: It looks like there is a DefinitelyTyped file for Mongoose as well as its extension of Promise [mongoose.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts). Have you referenced these files?

Comment: @Igor yes, however I do not want to use the Promise that Mongoose has by default, I replaced it with Bluebird. (by doing `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird')`)

Comment: Ok, what about referencing [DefinitelyTyped/bluebird/bluebird.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bluebird/bluebird.d.ts) and using a cast on the `save()` result?

Comment: Even "regular" promises have a `catch` method. It's only Mongoose promises that didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to DefinitelyTyped's mongoose.d.ts

```
/**
 * To assign your own promise library:
 *
 * 1. Include this somewhere in your code:
 *    mongoose.Promise = YOUR_PROMISE;
 *
 * 2. Include this somewhere in your main .d.ts file:
 *    type MongoosePromise<T> = YOUR_PROMISE<T>;
 */
```

So, your main .d.ts file would look like the following:

```
/// <reference path="globals/bluebird/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/mongoose/index.d.ts" />
type MongoosePromise<T> = bluebird.Promise<T>;
```

Comment: I don't have a 'main' `d.ts` file other than the one generated by Typings which I feel should not be modified. I tried adding that line where I define my model, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up doing this extending the mongoose module:

```
declare module "mongoose" {
    import Bluebird = require("bluebird");
    type MongoosePromise<T> = Bluebird<T>;
}
```

See my answer here : [Mongoose Promise with bluebird and typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39216034/4167200)

Comment: When I try that I get: `TS2665:Module augmentation cannot introduce new names in the top level scope.` what am I missing?

Comment: Where did you add these lines ? I've create a new gloabal.d.ts file and reference it in the index.d.ts. Also to get it work with latest mongoose package you need to target es6, see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39090151/4167200

Comment: I do not manage my .d.ts files manually , I let Typings take care of that. I added those lines inline in my model file.